# ValueError: Found unknown categories ['IR', 'HN', 'MT', 'PH', 'NZ', 'CZ', 'MD'] in column 3 during transform

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying to use Linear Regression, to predict salary in **USD**. I have the following data:

[image]

**Data:**

- **607** records
- **Numerical columns:** *year*, *salary*, *salary in USD*
- **Categorical columns:** *experience*, *type*, *residence*, *currency*, *remote work*, *company location*, and *company size*.
- **Target:** *salary in USD*

**Preprocessing dataset:**

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

# Columns to drop:
drop_cols = ['Currency', 'Company location', 'Salary', 'Title']

# Attributes of interest
num_attributes = ['Year']
one_hot_attributes = ['Experience', 'Type', 'Remote work', 'Residence', 'Company size']

# Drop columns:
data.drop(drop_cols, 1, inplace=True)

# Setup transformer for column:
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer([
    ('nums', StandardScaler(), num_attributes),
    ('one_hot', OneHotEncoder(drop='first', sparse=False), one_hot_attributes)], 
                                remainder='passthrough')
```

**Pipe:**

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

pipe = Pipeline(steps =[
    ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
    ('model', LinearRegression()),
])

pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

**Perform prediction:**

```
prediction = pipe.predict(X_test)

pd.DataFrame({'original test set':y_test, 'predictions': prediction})
```

**Error:**

```
ValueError: Found unknown categories ['IR', 'HN', 'MT', 'PH', 'NZ', 'CZ', 'MD'] in column 3 during transform
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is thrown by the `OneHotEncoder` class because your test dataset contains values for a column (likely the Residence column) that were not present in your training dataset. As specified in [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html), the default for the `handle_unknown` argument is to throw an error when new values are encountered when `transform` is called. Setting `handle_unknown='ignore'` should stop the error from being thrown.